# Как представить строку UTF-8 в виде массива байт и передать в функцию?

Tags: php

Есть код на шарпе:

```
var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("32 random chars");
```

В PHP мне нужно передать этот массив байт в качестве ключа шифрования в метод `mcrypt_encrypt`.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: у https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php параметры входные - это строки, а не массивы байт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, правда, зачем вам нужен массив байт, если [mcrypt_encrypt](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) принимает строки на входе.

Но используйте [unpack](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.unpack.php), если уж так надо:

```
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $my_string);
```